# Android to upload images to user facebook wall

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

As I know, in order for mobile app to upload images to user facebook wall, i will need a fb app that have the following permission:

1. User_photo
2. publish_action

But these permissions requires submission and being reviewed by facebook team.
Before facebook team grants the permission to my fb app, can my mobile app able to upload images to user facebook wall?

Comment: @KishanDhamat
I haven't tried yet. I only can test after work hour .. :P
Is it even the original app doesn't have the permission, the test app will still able to post images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to create a testing application as described by @Kishan Dhamat.
But unfortunately, I got an error regarding to the user doesn't grant the app the permission to do so.
After google for awhile, I found that there is an [example](https://github.com/fbsamples/android-3.0-howtos/blob/master/PublishFeedHowTo/src/com/facebook/samples/publishfeedhowto/MainFragment.java) explicitly requesting for the required permission. What I did is trigger this code for getting user permission to post images.

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                            .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by creating testing application.

Just do this things;

1. Go to this link [Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/)
2. Now create new app.

[image]

3. Now when you creating new app put that button on for testing app and select original app which you are testing.
4. Add your application testers in the developer console in app. settings  and it will work.
5. copy application id in your project. and run it.

It will work without submitting your app.
Thanks,